# Rails ActiveRecord polymorphic associated relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've made a Rails app where I have tags, which I can use to tag various other models, however unlike a normal polymorphic relationship there is only 1 tag record for each tag name and then I used a join model called "TagRealtionship" to track what has been tagged and has a tag id and taggable id and well as tagable type. Right now I'm working with the tags and the blogs models. Here's what the models look like:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tag_relationships, :as => :tagable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tags, :through => :tag_relationships

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tag_relationships, dependent: :destroy

class TagRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tagable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :tag
```

What I'm trying to do it pull up all the Blogs that match a certain tag. If I take a tag model and run this query...

```
@tag.tag_relationships.where(tagable_type: "Blog")
```

I get an association relation like this

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<TagRelationship id: 1, tag_id: 1, tagable_id:        108, tagable_type: "Blog", created_at: "2014-06-26 18:45:50", updated_at: "2014-06-26 18:45:50">, #<TagRelationship id: 2, tag_id: 1, tagable_id: 102, tagable_type: "Blog", created_at: "2014-06-26 18:46:10", updated_at: "2014-06-26 18:46:10">, #<TagRelationship id: 3, tag_id: 1, tagable_id: 127, tagable_type: "Blog", created_at: "2014-06-26 20:28:29", updated_at: "2014-06-26 20:28:29">]>
```

If I take one of those records and I call .tagable on it and I can get the blog post but I'm wondering if there is a way I can query and get an ActiveRecord collection for all the matching blog posts. I know if I do .map(&:tagable) it will give me an array of the blog posts but I need the Active Record collection so I can filter it down a bit further and paginate the posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put another way, you want to get a list of blog posts for a particular tag, correct?

```
# Find all blog posts where tag id = 1
Blog.includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: 1})
```

You could also add a scope to the Blog model to make this easier to use:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_relationships, :as => :tagable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_relationships

  scope :tagged_with, -> (tag) {
    includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: tag.id})
  end
end
```

And use the new scope like this:

```
tag = Tag.find(1)
Blog.tagged_with(tag)
```